# How do I read unstructured csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In python, how can I read an unstructured csv file (with some redundant rows of texts) and output it as a new structured csv file using pandas?

There are some unwanted rows in the csv file (at the very beginning as shown by the picture) which is getting parsed as a unique column resulting in incorrect format of columns, but actually these lines should be ignored

The unstructured csv [image: csv]

The Desired Structure : [image: Structure]

**I have searched for a solution, but none of the previous questions here solve my problem**

Comment: Which solutions have you already tried and why do they not work for your problem?

Comment: If you can share code showing how you consume the csv and try to reorganize the rows/columns it's more likely that somebody can help.  Sort of asking yourself the questions you pose here.  And in doing so, you may stumble upon the solution.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging